# Invalid Syntax - Shapely Spatial Operation

Tags: python, graph, gis, shapely

I am trying to use the ['.within'](http://toblerity.org/shapely/shapely.geometry.html) function from Shapely...just a simple check and I can't get around this syntax error.

I was just trying to recreate the example I saw in the [docs.](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html)

Code is:

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

>>> LineString([(-9765787.9981184918000000 5488940.9749489054000000, -9748582.8016368076000000 5488402.1275707092000000)]).within(Point(-9763788.9782693591000000 5488878.3678984242000000))
```

Returns:

```
 >> Traceback (  File "<interactive input>", line 1
    LineString([(-9765787.9981184918000000 5488940.9749489054000000, -9748582.8016368076000000 5488402.1275707092000000)]).within(Point(-9763788.9782693591000000 5488878.3678984242000000))
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1) Load the WKT string:

```
from shapely.wkt import loads as wkt_loads
line = wkt_loads('LINESTRING(-9765787.9981184918000000 5488940.9749489054000000, -9748582.8016368076000000 5488402.1275707092000000)')
point = wkt_loads('POINT(-9763788.9782693591000000 5488878.3678984242000000)')
```

2) Format a list of properly formatted coordinate pairs as regular Python floats:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
line = LineString([(-9765787.9981184918000000, 5488940.9749489054000000), (-9748582.8016368076000000, 5488402.1275707092000000)])
point = Point(-9763788.9782693591000000, 5488878.3678984242000000)
```

Next, you will encounter some floating point precision errors with your test:

```
line.within(point)  # False
line.distance(point)  # 7.765244949417793e-11
line.distance(point) < 1e-8  # True
```

I'd recommend the last testing method to determine if the point is on the line.

Answer (score 0):

got it.

```
>> LineString([(-9765787.9981184918000000,5488940.9749489054000000), (-9748582.8016368076000000,5488402.1275707092000000)]).within(Point(-9765787.9981184918000000,5488940.9749489054000000))
```